# Transition not working on hover

Tags: css, hover, transition, mousehover

I don't know but for some reasons, transition doesn't seem to be working. I am testing this Google Chrome.

```css
[data-title] {
 position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
}

[data-title]:hover:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
 width: 18px;
 height: 6px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: 0px;
 top: 100%;
 opacity: 1;
 pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-left: 8px solid transparent;
 border-right: 8px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #00204e;
  
}

[data-title]:hover:after {
 transform: translate(-50%, 0);
 left: calc(50%);
 margin-top: 10px;
 top: 100%;
 opacity: 1;
 pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-shadow: none;
 background: #00204e;
 border-radius: 4px;
 color: #fff;
 content: attr(data-title);
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 white-space: normal;
 width: max-content;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
 line-height: normal;
 max-width: 150px;
 text-align: left;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="dijitButtonContents" id="saveButton" data-title="Save as draft"><span id="saveButton_label">Save</span></span>
```

Can anyone help where I am going wrong or am I missing something?

I have even tried to make transition timing to +1 seconds but still it doesn't reflects the same.

Comment: But you dont have any styles for unhovered `:before` and `:after`

Comment: Yes because this is a tooltip that I only need on hover.

Comment: So you code does exactly what you wrote.

Comment: What are you wanting to animate?

Comment: @Pete I am trying to animate the tooltip that is appearing on hover.

Comment: Yes I know but how - fade in, scroll in from the left?  what property are you trying to animate?

Comment: I need to apply fade-in and out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not set anything for the original state so the transition doesn't know what to go from.  If you are only wanting to transition the item's appearance - eg fade in or out, then you need to do something like transition the opacity:

```css
[data-title] {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
}

[data-title]:before {
  width: 18px;
  height: 6px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #00204e;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

[data-title]:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  left: calc(50%);
  margin-top: 10px;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #00204e;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-title);
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: normal;
  width: max-content;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  line-height: normal;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

[data-title]:hover:before,
[data-title]:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<span class="dijitButtonContents" id="saveButton" data-title="Save as draft"><span id="saveButton_label">Save</span></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something to `transition` from one state to another, you have to define both states. This means having a base-style and a `:hover`-style.

For example:

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.test:hover {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">test</div>
```

This works, because there is an initial state for the `height` attribute. This however:

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.test:hover {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">test</div>
```

This will not work, because the browser doesn't have a specified `height` as an initial state.

Comment: Can you answer my original question as what changes need to be done since I am using :before and :after elements?

Comment: That depends on what you want, you have a `transition: all` so I have no idea what you want to transition. If you want to transition everything, then you need to create a base state for every property.